# React Native, Invariant Violation: Native component for "AIRMap" does not exist

Tags: google-maps, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to install `react-native-maps`
I followed the document for installation.

My install process was like below.

#### I used react-native link instead of cocoaPod.

- npm i react-native-maps --save
- myProj.xcodeproj/Libraries => Add files to "myProj" click
- add myProj/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/ios/AirMaps.xcodeproj
- myProj click => Build Phases, Link Binary with libraries => add `libArMaps.a`
- react-native link react-native-maps

However, build failed.

> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
>
> CompileC /Users/dadumvu/work/foodup-mobile-RN/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/AirMaps.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AirMaps.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AIRGoogleMapPolygonManager.o AirGoogleMaps/AIRGoogleMapPolygonManager.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>   (1 failure)

My version's here.

`"react-native-maps": "^0.21.0"`

`"react-native": "0.55.4"`

If anyone could solve this issue, please let me know about it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

like this [How to fix"AIRMap" was not found in the UIManager error in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51318063/how-to-fixairmap-was-not-found-in-the-uimanager-error-in-react-native/51853775#51853775)

## Add to `ios/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/AppDelegate.m`

`@import GoogleMaps; //add this line if you want to use Google Maps`

and

`[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"_YOUR_API_KEY_"]; // add this line using the api key obtained from Google Console`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but still, it doesn't work.
I guess it can't import googlemap

#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
1 error generated.